# LLVM Fortran function to get process identifier

Tags: function, fortran, llvm

Does LLVM Fortran compiler (similar to [GNU](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GETPID.html) or Intel) provide a function `getpid()` or its equivalent to return the process identifier?

Comment: No idea, but it shouldn't be too difficult to us C interoperability to call the OS function directly - the biggest problem probably is working out what a pid_t is.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing simpler then opening the compiler's page and check the manual, or the source code. In this code it was actually faster to check the Github project, it is certainly faster than asking at StackOverflow... The getpid function is there among all other intrinsics https://github.com/flang-compiler/flang/tree/master/runtime/flang . Specifically, it is (non surprisingly) in the sourcefile that starts wth `getpid...` https://github.com/flang-compiler/flang/blob/master/runtime/flang/getpid3f.c

And then you can simply clone the project and try `find . -type f | xargs grep -in "getpid"` to find even more locations or even build the compiler and try the Fortran code.